# R=301 from domain.tld/index.php?id=1 to domain.tld

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this. This is not changing `domain.tld/index.php?id=1` to `domain.tld` in browser address bar. How to make rule that will work correctly making permanent 301 redirect?

```
RewriteRule ^domain.tld$ domain.tld/index.php?id=1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this. You cannot match against the host (`domain.tld`) in a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! Also how add to this rule redirect of empty query string like `/index.php` to `/`?

Comment: @A-STAR just remove the line with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [OR]` right before it

Comment: Yes, that works with `^$`. I tried simply remove before and no luck. Why we need this string `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.tld$ [NC]` here? What it does?

Comment: @A-STAR it checks to make sure the request is for the host `domain.tld`, it's not needed if you don't care about the host. You had it in your question so I added it.